# Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$student_model

Tags: codeigniter

Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$student_model.............

I'm getting the error like this:

```
<?php  


class Student extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
}


public function index(){
    echo "this is  a index";
}

 public function getall(){

    $this->load->model('Student_model');
    $data['query']=$this->db->student_model->student_getall;
    $this->load->view('student_viewall',$data);

}

function get($id){

    $this->load->model('student_model');
    $data['query'] =$this->db->student_model->student_get($id);
    $this->load->view('student_view',$data);

}



}

?>
```

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Answer (score 2):

Your error is calling the model incorrectly:

instead of `$data['query']=$this->db->student_model->student_getall;`

it should be

```
$data['query']=$this->student_model->student_getall();
```

then in your model function student_getall() you do something like:

```
    $query = $this->db->get('students');
    $data=($query->num_rows() ) ?$query->result():false;    
    return $data;
```

last, in your view you retrieve data like this:

```
<div class="studentlist">
    <?php foreach($query as $row):?>                                                                              
        <div class="studentlist_row">
            <?=$row->student_name?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach ?> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling student model incorrect way. Bellow are the errors you have done. I am making them bold.

1. Student_model: please make sure 1st char of the class name is in caps and its file name also follows the same caps combination.
2. Once the model is loaded you can call any method or variable of that model by `$this->Model_name->Method_name()`
3. `$data['query']=$this->db->student_model->student_getall;` in this statement, I am expecting `student_getall` is a method and should be called like this `student_getall()`:  `$data['query']=$this->Student_model->student_getall();`

For more information about model follow this documentation: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html
    
    class Student extends CI_Controller{

```
function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
}


public function index(){
    echo "this is  a index";
}

 public function getall(){

    $this->load->model('Student_model');
    $data['query']=$this->Student_model->student_getall();
    $this->load->view('student_viewall',$data);

}

function get($id){

    $this->load->model('Student_model');
    $data['query'] =$this->Student_model->student_get($id);
    $this->load->view('student_view',$data);

}



}

?>
```